# NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"' : return code '0x1'

Tags: windows, php, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create a php extension using c/c++.

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 with modified installation:

- only install MSVC v140 - VS 2015 C++ builds tools (v14.00)
- Install Workloads `Windows`

and also downloaded php7.1.28 source.

The following is my file at `C:\php-7.1.28\ext\helloworld\`

File: `config.w32`

```
ARG_ENABLE("helloworld", "helloworld support", "no");

if (PHP_HELLOWORLD == "yes") {
    EXTENSION("helloworld", "php_helloworld.c", true);
}
```

File: `php_helloworld.h`

```
// we define Module constants
#define PHP_HELLOWORLD_EXTNAME "php_helloworld"
#define PHP_HELLOWORLD_VERSION "0.0.1"

// then we declare the function to be exported
PHP_FUNCTION(helloworld_php);
```

File: `php_helloworld.c`

```
// include the PHP API itself
#include <php.h>
// then include the header of your extension
#include "php_helloworld.h"

// register our function to the PHP API 
// so that PHP knows, which functions are in this module
zend_function_entry helloworld_php_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(helloworld_php, NULL)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

// some pieces of information about our module
zend_module_entry helloworld_php_module_entry = {
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
    PHP_HELLOWORLD_EXTNAME,
    helloworld_php_functions,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    PHP_HELLOWORLD_VERSION,
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

// use a macro to output additional C code, to make ext dynamically loadable
ZEND_GET_MODULE(helloworld_php)

// Finally, we implement our "Hello World" function
// this function will be made available to PHP
// and prints to PHP stdout using printf
PHP_FUNCTION(helloworld_php) {
    php_printf("Hello World! (from our extension)\n");
}
```

After I wanna make the extension using `php7.1.28` source with compiler `MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)` the following log is my error.

```
C:\php-7.1.28>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24245.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Recreating build dirs 
type ext\pcre\php_pcre.def > C:\php-7.1.28\x64\Release_TS\php7ts.dll.def
"" -h win32\ -r C:\php-7.1.28\x64\Release_TS\ -x C:\php-7.1.28\x64\Release_TS\ 
win32\build\wsyslog.mc
'-h' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

Why am I getting the errors and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

An error like that witnesses the absent Windows 10 SDK. There should be better error messages in the later PHP versions, the tools needed from there are `mt.exe` and `mc.exe`.

Other than that, I'd recommend using the [documented Visual Studio versions](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/compiler) and [SDK](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2) for better experience.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. But I have fixed this problem by installing Old Version of Visual Studio 2015, not VS 2019, directly from the site and it work perfectly.